# perl (good practice): lexical filehandle for socket

Tags: perl, sockets

In perdoc [Socket](http://perldoc.perl.org/Socket.html) page, they use global filehandle for socket.
But if I create a socket in a subroutine called by child processes, is it better to use lexical filehandle still using Socket ?

like this:

```
use strict;
use Socket;
sub sendData
{
    my $proto = getprotobyname('tcp');
    my $socket;
    socket($socket, PF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, $proto);
    ...
    close($socket)
}
```

instead of:

```
sub sendData
{
    my $proto = getprotobyname('tcp');
    socket(SOCKET, PF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, $proto);
    ...
    close(SOCKET)
}
```

It seems to be ok, but I don't know if it's a better practice or completely useless...

Thanks

Comment: Actually, this has been fixed in [recent versions](https://metacpan.org/module/Socket) of Socket

Answer (score 10):

Yes, it's a better practice to use lexical filehandles.  But Perl 5.0 didn't have them, so there's plenty of older code and documentation that uses global filehandles, and much of it hasn't been updated to use lexical ones.

P.S. You know that you can say

```
socket(my $socket, PF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, $proto);
```

instead of putting the `my` on the previous line, right?

Comment: I dearly wish people would stop misapplying the term “lexical filehandle” to what they **really** mean, which is “autovivved filehandle”.

Answer (score 1):

Yes its always better to use lexical scoped instead of global. If you need unique handles, though global, try [Symbol package](http://search.cpan.org/~flora/perl-5.14.2/lib/Symbol.pm)

Comment: Yes, that's from the doc. You have handle in a glob.

Comment: "Symbol::gensym creates an anonymous glob and returns a reference to it. Such a glob reference can be used as a file or directory handle."


ok but with code "my $socket", and using it in socket() or open() for file, perl creates an anonymous lexical filehandle also, no?

Comment: Yeah, open and socket autovivify the file-handle

Answer (score 1):

The `Socket` module is useful if you need to do some low level tweaking with how your sockets are configured, but for most uses, if not nearly all uses, the [`IO::Socket::INET`](http://p3rl.org/IO%3a%3aSocket%3a%3aINET) module provides a simpler interface. Its constructor returns the socket's handle as an object, bypassing the need to worry about the global filehandle.